# Mysql Joins- Results are duplicated how to fix it

Tags: mysql, database

I am very new to MySQL and also this is my first question if  there is any mistakes please forgive me.

I have **6 tables** i want to take **report** using this **6 tables**. One of my report to access all the 6 tables and print the data as per the Query we write.Now the problem is i have write my query but this will return lot of duplicate data.How to avoid that guide me please.

```
    SELECT 
         @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS RowNumber, 
         a.vnumber,a.vname, 
         b.eid,b.name,b.mobile, 

         c.vid,c.emp_id,c.pick_place,c.start_time,c.drop_place,c.stop_time,
         c.pickupkm,c.drops,c.type_of_trip,c.travelkm,c.tamt,c.dates,
         d.vid,d.emp_id,d.expcal,d.exp1,d.exp2,d.exp3,
         d.exp4,d.exp5,d.expamt,d.expdesc,d.dates, 
         e.emp_id,e.vid,e.opeing_km,e.opeing_cash,e.closing_km,

         e.closing_cash,e.opeing_date,e.opeing_time,e.closing_date,
         e.closing_time, f.vid,f.emp_id,
         f.totkm,f.totamt,f.expenses,f.handover_amt,
         f.balance_amt,f.handover_to,f.plstatus,f.entry_date 

  from 
         add_vehicle a 

         LEFT JOIN third_table c ON a.vnumber=c.vid 
         LEFT JOIN add_employees b ON b.eid=c.emp_id 
         LEFT JOIN fourth_table d ON a.vnumber=d.vid 
         LEFT JOIN shift e ON b.eid=e.emp_id 
         LEFT JOIN five_table f ON a.vnumber=f.vid, 

(SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
        WHERE 
              c.type_of_trip IS NOT NULL AND 
              c.dates BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-19' AND 
              d.dates BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-19' AND 
              f.entry_date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-19' AND 
              c.vid='STAT01' AND f.vid='STAT01' AND c.emp_id='1' AND 
              f.emp_id='1' AND e.emp_id='1' 

ORDER BY c.dates,f.entry_date DESC
```

> sorry for SQL fiddle not working.

This is my Tables and sample data.

[My sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8pzY.png)

Comment: Add example data and expected output

Comment: You probably have multiple records from one of the tables matching a single record in another table. Pls provide us with sample data, the actual results received on the sample data using your current query, and the expected results.

Comment: okay i try to add friends

Comment: i update my question with sample data @juergend

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use "group by" by the column you wish to be unique, or use "distinct"

Answer (score 0):

you can use GROUP BY function for avoiding duplicate data. Just use group by for those data whome you want to be unique. Example like below

```
 GROUP BY eid
```

Add this query at the end so you can avoid same employee.

Also you can use INNER JOIN